# Fetch a service principle client ID having only its display name

Tags: bash, azure, azure-cli

The following bash script code used to work to get a service principal's client ID via AZ CLI, by passing its display name to the script.

```
az ad sp show --id http://$SP_NAME
```

But now I am getting the following error :

> Service principal ... doesn't exist

The `$SP_NAME` variable contains the exact same display name as I see in the App Registrations in Azure AD.

---

When deploying a service principal via script, we do not have the service principal object ID prior to running the script, only the name we want to assign to the service principal (display name). Not only this used to work a few months back, as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az_ad_sp_show) it should still work!

---

Any idea how can I make it work again?

Comment: There are several possibilities. Did you verify that the service principal exists under App Registrations?

Comment: have you also checked if `$SP_NAME` contains any value?

Comment: @JohnHanley yes it exists there

Comment: @Melissa yes it contains

Comment: I think you mean this command **az ad sp list --display-name $SP_NAME**

Comment: That is another way to achieve what I want, but adds some complexity to something that used to be easy, and should remain easy. The output of that command is a list, thus after running it, I would then need to fetch the first element of the list, and read the objectId. And I did not manage to find an easy way to read the first element of a list in a bash script...

Comment: Use the tools **jq** to parse the output. Note: I do not remember the command ever working with your syntax. the **--id** option does not accept the **Display Name**.

Comment: I am 100% sure it did work. Have you opened the link I posted with the documentation? It confirms it should indeed work

Comment: Well, you are correct and the command you are using works on my system. Use my command and double-check the **displayName** that you are using from the output.

Comment: I used your command, and in the displayName field there's exactly what I have been using in $SP_NAME. Even if I copy paste it, use double or single quotes with, the error message is still the same : Service principal ... doesn't exist. However, there's a field named "servicePrincipalNames", which is a list, and there I can find a GUID, which I can indeed use with az ad sp show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When executing the command `az ad sp show --id http://$SP_NAME` it tries to resolve the service principal by searching the exact id in the `ServicePrincipalNames` element of the AD Application object, as shown [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/39a717bc5076758cc3a46961905207f62c0fd80a/src/azure-cli/azure/cli/command_modules/acs/custom.py#L1330) on the az cli Github.

When you create a service principal, be sure to add `http://$SP_NAME` as an application identifier URI, like below.
[image: app registration overview]

Then if you go to the Manifest of that App Registration, the Application ID URI  is shown under `identifierUris`.
[image: identifier URIs]

The `ServicePrincipalNames` element is a collection of identifiers. So now the command should output the correct service principal.
[image: output]

Comment: @ccoutinho Glad to hear you've resolved the issue :)